# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available

Tags: java, spring, openjpa

Need help to resolve below issue .

**Background :**
I am using OpenJPA and spring 3.x in a standalone application to retrieve data from db2 database.I don't require transaction management as my requirement is only to read data from database.

Please find below configuration in my spring application context file :

```
<bean id="testEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testPersistence" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
        value="classpath:META-INF/testPersistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="testEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:changeControl.properties" />
</bean>
```

configuration in testPersistence.xml is :

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="changeControlPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>


    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="db2abc" />
        <property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="fetch-groups" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Please find below exception stack trace :

```
14  testPersistence  WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'testPersistence', root URL [file:/C:/scm/scbu-ods-core/scbu-ods-control-entities/target/classes/]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.principal.scbu.zos.test.ZOSTest.main(ZOSTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.checkUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:474)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: There is no other error before this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

by

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Still facing the same issue

Comment: and try to replace org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager by org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager